# Null exception error on dbString=" ";

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I often come across null exception errors and I always end up solving them, except this time I'm stuck with this error for days now.

Here it is:

In my mainActivity I need to print some data from the database through this method

```
  public void printDB(){

    String dbString= WinToDB.dbToString();
    wordDB.setText(dbString);
    word.setText("");

    meaningDB.setText(dbString);
    meaning.setText("");
}
```

dbString should carry what this this method from my database handler is returning

```
 public String dbToString(){
    dbString="";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME +  " WHERE 1 ";  // * star means all 'columns' 1 means all 'row'

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //move to first location
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wishe")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wishe"));
            dbString += "\n";

        }
    }
    db.close();
   // db.releaseReference();

    return dbString;
}
```

But it throws *attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*

here's the logcat:

> .RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mirdox.myapplication/com.mirdox.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                        at com.mirdox.myapplication.MainActivity.printDB(MainActivity.java:79)
>                                                        at com.mirdox.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

What's wrong and what should I do? 
Thanks in advance!

***EDIT*** Here's the onCreate of my mainActivity `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText word, meaning;
TextView wordDB, meaningDB;
DBhandler WinToDB;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    WinToDB= new DBhandler(this, null, null, 1);
    printDB();

    //_________input________________________
    word= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.word);
    meaning= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.meaning);

    //_________output_______________________
    wordDB= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    meaningDB= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

****EDIT 2 Here is my content_main.xml: I'had a problem adding the code to here; here's the link to code on evernote[content_main.xml](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s543/sh/662945a2-3f7f-4a0c-bffd-ff1618f9b9b5/3863c21c1fc427877768b5ae874c7bea)

ps: I have the printDb(); written in onCreate in the mainAcitvity.

Comment: Where is `wordDB` declared?

Comment: The problem is not `dbString` it is the `TextView` you are trying to set that is null. Make sure you are using the proper res id and make sure the view is properly inflated before trying to set the text.

Comment: Have you initialized "wordDB" ?

Comment: @Gendarme Yes, I also added my mainAcitivity. Could you have a look please

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe  I checked the xml id's and they're correct and I'm not inflating it. I've just added my mainAcitivity, could you have a look please.

Comment: @Shadab Ansari yes.  I've just added my mainAcitivity, could you have a look please

Comment: Please post your activity_main.xml

Comment: Then the next thing to check is to make sure these are actually declared as TextViews and are actually located in `activity_main.xml`. If you want you can post `activity_main.xml` and we can have a look.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I just added it as link to my evernote

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe I checked but they're correct :/  I added my content_main.xml as link above.

Comment: You are calling printDB(); before initializing your views. That's why you are getting excepttion. Call printDB();  after initializing your views.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Damn I didn't I was this dumb! thanks a lot I can now launch it on my phone! :)

Answer (score 0):

`wordDB`, `word`, `meaningDB` or `meaning` is `null`, whichever is on line 79.